# How does pictonic work?

Tags: css, fonts, web

Can anyone explain to me how https://pictonic.co/ works? I'm interested in creating my own imageless icons, but I'm not sure what the best strategy is to attack this, and knowing what techniques they use seems like a good starting point. Can anyone tell from their demo?

Comment: I think the tagline "Font icons" in the header there should tell you all you need to know.

Comment: The designer of the website wrote an article describing the techinques used to design the icons, http://blog.pictonic.co/post/31265656514/designing-icons-for-use-in-icon-fonts

Answer (score 0):

I'm the lead developer at pictonic.

Our designer recently wrote an article describing the techniques he used to design the icons, this might go some way towards answering your question:

http://blog.pictonic.co/post/31265656514/designing-icons-for-use-in-icon-fonts

The output of this is a bunch of svgs. We have our own techniques for processing these, but essentially, i would point you towards the www.w3.org specification for svg fonts:

http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/fonts.html

good luck! : >